# Always getting null response when i call an API with city with spaces at openweathermap.com

Tags: android, retrofit, openweathermap

I'm getting a null response when i call API with city with spaces: for example "San Francisco". When for example "Mexico" is working fine.

i've tried replacing spaces with "+", but it' doesn't work in android. But in postman it worked.

here's call code:

```
Api api = ApiBuilder.createApi();
    Call<CurrentWeather> currentWeatherCall = 
api.getCurrentWeather(API_KEY, "san+francisco", UNITS);

    currentWeatherCall.enqueue(new Callback<CurrentWeather>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CurrentWeather> call, 
Response<CurrentWeather> response) {
            try {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response.body().getCityName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `logging-interceptor` then you can see response from the server in Verbose Log.

in Gradle
`implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'`

in Interface

```
 public static PostService postService = null;

        public static PostService getService() {
        if (postService == null) {
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
           .addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(base_url)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
            postService = retrofit.create(PostService.class);

        }
        return postService;
        }
```

if api call is made then server response can be seen in Verbose then you debug

Comment: Thanks, i logged with okhttp and problem is: i need plus sign instead of 252b in URL

Comment: can you help please, i can't replace 252b into plus sign

Comment: can you share the function ````getCurrentWeather()```` of interface